# I want to add a SearchView to my listview

Tags: java, android, searchview

I want to add a SearchView to my list so that the user can look for a specific content in the listview

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    private RecyclerView.Adapter mAdapter;
    private RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager;
    List<Book> books;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        books = new ArrayList<>();
        books.add(new Book("Rich Dad Poor Dad", "Rich Dad Poor Dad is a 1997 book written by Robert Kiyosaki and Sharon Lechter.", "Robert Kiyosaki"));
        books.add(new Book("Awaken The Giant Within", "Wake up and take control of your life! From the bestselling author of Inner Strength, Unlimited Power, and MONEY Master the Game", "Anthony Robbins"));

        mRecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.my_recyclerview);
        mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        mAdapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(books, this);

        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Custom Filtering in listview android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17276260/custom-filtering-in-listview-android)

Comment: Have a look here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27378981/how-to-use-searchview-in-toolbar-android and

Comment: Just add an EditText to your layout and use that to filter your query.

Comment: EditText + filter is much better.  The SearchView and Search API in general was a giant mistake.